# useState to update multiple values in react with one change changing the all the remaining

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've a series of data elements which i am using hooks on.

```
const [a, setA] = useState(true);
const [b, setB] = useState(false);
const [c, setC] = useState(false);
const [d, setD] = useState(false);
```

i have used a map to loop through all these four and change them on a click using a function `changeOnClick`. The function basically reverses the current value and sets the value of all other useStates to `false`. the function looks like(`approach A`):

```
const changeOnClick = (x) => {
    switch (x) {
      case "a":
        setA(!a);
        setB(false);
        setC(false);
        setD(false);
        break;
      case "b":
        setB(!b);
        setA(false);
        setC(false);
        setD(false);
        break;
      .
      .


      default:
        break;
    }
  }
```

i have tried using these 4 values as an useState object(`approach B`), i.e.

```
const [all, setAll] = useState({
   a: true, 
   b: false, 
   c: false, 
   d: false
});
```

but i can't work out a way to use the `changeOnClick` function. It obviously works with `approach A`, but i want to learn a new way to use / make the code look succinct.
Would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways to ***update the object using `useState()`*** is to recall the `prevState` (previous State), `spread` it `(... prevState)` and change the property you wish in the setter function, like

```
setAll((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    a : !prevState.a, // or false 
}));
```

---

***A bit more detailed usage based on your code***

```
const [all, setAll] = useState({
   a: true, 
   b: false, 
   c: false, 
   d: false
}); 


const changeOnClick = (x) => {
    switch (x) {
      case "a": setAll((prevState) => ({
                  ...prevState,
                  a : !prevState.a, // or false 
                 }));
                 break;
      case "b": setAll((prevState) => ({
                  ...prevState,
                  b : !prevState.b, // or false  as you wiss
                 }));
                 break;
      ...
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

If only one of those states is allowed to be true, then perhaps use a single state and record which feature is active. e.g. setState('a') or setState('b').

I think what you want is to use a curried function.
Sorry if there's syntax error, typing this live:

```
<button onClick={updateState('a')}>AAA</button>
<button onClick={updateState('b')}>BBB</button>
<button onClick={updateState('c')}>CCC</button>
<button onClick={updateState('d')}>DDD</button>

const updateState = (whichState) => (event) => {
   console.log('whichState', whichState)
   console.log('event', event)
   // your code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I can suggest is to create a dummy object in the handler itself.

```
const clonedAll = {
        a: false,
        b: false,
        c: false,
        d: false,
    };
```

After that in the handler as you are passing the value `x` which is the key itself. Modify the setState with de-structuring the object and adding the value true to the key itself.

```
setAll({
        ...clonedAll,
        [x]: true,
    });
```

Also assign a default value to `x` for default value to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change state like that:

```js
setA(!a);
```

but like this:

```js
setA((prevState) => !prevState)
```

Try to read about [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

Comment: This is a general best practice, but will not have any affect on their code since they are not updating that state more than once per render or within a closure. So while not wrong in any way, this doesn't actually address the question.

Answer (score 0):

Then probable you should read a Lil More istead of asking. But here Is an option

```
...
const [data, setData]=useState({});
...

const changeHandler = e => {
 const name = e.target.getAttribute("name");
 const value = e.target.value;

 setData({...data, { [name]: value });
}
...
return (
 <input name="firstName" onChange={changeHamdler}/>

 <input name="lastName" onChange={changeHamdler}/>

 <input name="password" onChange={changeHamdler}/>
);
```